# Oracle sql, select First Row while selecting other things

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

What do I need to add to the query below to get just the first row that shows up after this query?

Query:

```
  SELECT column1,
         column2,
         MIN (column3),
         MIN (colmun4)
    FROM table
   WHERE column0 = 'value'
GROUP BY column1, column2
```

Current Results:

```
column1  column2  column3  column4
30187    C        201330   1/3/2013 2:49:35 PM    //I want this row only
33459    C        201330   1/3/2013 4:32:42 PM
90855    C        201390   3/28/2013 9:20:44 AM
96077    RA       201390   7/1/2013 11:31:46 AM
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from (
SELECT column1,
         column2,
         MIN (column3),
         MIN (colmun4)
    FROM table
   WHERE column0 = 'value'
GROUP BY column1, column2)
where rownum = 1
```

or if you're using oracle 12c you can use the below,

```
    SELECT column1,
             column2,
             MIN (column3),
             MIN (colmun4)
        FROM table
       WHERE column0 = 'value'
    GROUP BY column1, column2
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY;
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know I could wrap a select around another select like this.